# interesting programming technology from old times

Tags: language-agnostic, history

If you are old programmer or are history of programming/computing buff, what is an interesting programming/computing technology which you liked, which is marginalized today?

In other words, which technology do you miss from old times?

ps:  feel free to make this question sound more English

Comment: Probably better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

[APL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language)), before hearing about functional languages, I had the chance to play with this language full of funny symbols and mathematical operators. It looked like hieroglyphics all right but it was so succint and expressive! And it was good for getting on the nerves of my more traditional Pascal or C oriented fellow students :p

Comment: I looked at it sometime ago, however alphabet was just overpowering.

Comment: There exists a reincarnation of APL named J. As cryptic as the predecessor, though without those arcane characters.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J_%28programming_language%29

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of anything I miss, specifically. Things I don't miss:

- [x86 segmented architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation)
- [extended](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_memory)/[expanded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expanded_memory) memory
- [DOS TSRs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminate_and_Stay_Resident)
- [IPX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internetwork_Packet_Exchange)
- [config.sys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Config.sys)/[autoexec.bat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AUTOEXEC.BAT)
- [X.25](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.25)

Answer (score 2):

Forth and Ada.

Forth programs were more compact than you could imagine (of course they were, they were just long lists of pointers, referencing the stack!), and the language was executing fast as hell on cheap hardware.

Ada came with a nicer, although exotic, when compared to C++, object programming model. It had useful constructs you don't find in C++, while still being compiled. For one, Ada has concurrency built in, whereas C++ as a language has no idea of concurrency. Ada also has stronger and more reasonable type checking than C++.

Answer (score 0):

- serial ports
- parallel ports
- punch cards
- token ring networks (BNC connectors, UGH!)

Comment: do you miss punchcards, in the sense, is it technology you are glad is gone?

Comment: @aaa carp: Miss one, you have to start over from the beginning... Yes, glad it's gone.

Comment: RS-232 is straightforward and simple. I miss that. And no, buggy serial-USB adapters aren't the same.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta: RJ-45, *minimum*

Answer (score 0):

About the only thing I can think of worth missing is SNOBOL. I'll go out on a limb and predit that Perl 9 (or *maybe* 10) will come close to catching up with SNOBOL 3 (but even I'm not brave enough to predict when Perl will catch up with SNOBOL 4).

Then again, given the gestation period for Perl 6, I'm not sure I'll live long enough to know when/if it does happen.